# Integrating a LCD Display in a widget that shows the line number of the textEdit

Tags: pyqt4

I want to get the line number of a textEdit in pyqt when the mouse cursor is clicked on a particular line . Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gives you an idea:

```
    self.connect(self.ui.textEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("cursorPositionChanged()"),self.lineNumber)
```

and later:

```
    def lineNumber(self):
        # we try to get the lineNumber on change of cursor position
        theLineNumber = self.ui.textEdit.textCursor().blockNumber()
        self.ui.label.setText('Ln : '+str(theLineNumber))
```